# Generating tooltips with cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to replicate the helpful tooltip feature of the old cytoscape web.  Is there a way to attach a tooltip to nodes and edges in the new cytoscape.js?  I've tried looking for this function, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Cytoscape.js qTip extension : https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip

--

Original answer:

I will be porting over some of my own code to a separate qtip interface plugin soon.  In the meanwhile, you may find this code useful:

https://github.com/PathwayCommons/factoid/blob/master/lib/app/client/qtip.js

Comment: Thanks @maxkfranz. If this will be released as a plugin later I'll wait for that instead of implementing my own :) Do you have an idea of when this will be released?

Comment: I'll try to put it in the upcoming 2.1 release (issue #322) -Max